# bash set with double equal sign ==

Tags: bash

What does double equal sign `==` mean in a set invocation in bash script?
Below is an example taken from [here](https://github.com/Juniper/contrail-test/blob/master/testrunner.sh#L587):

```
for arg in "$@"; do
    shift
    case "$arg" in
        "--help") set -- "$@" "-h" ;;
        "--feature") set -- "$@" "-f" ;;
        "--log-path") set -- "$@" "-p" ;;
        "--shell") set == "$@" "-s";;
        "--scenarios") set == "$@" "-S";;
        "--ssh-key") set == "$@" "-k";;
        "--ssh-public-key") set == "$@" "-K";;
        "--background") set == "$@" "-b";;
        "--no-color") set == "$@" "-n";;
        "--all") set == "$@" "-a" ;;
        "--params-file") set == "$@" "-P" ;;
        "--use-ci-image") set == "$@" "-i" ;;
        *) set -- "$@" "$arg"
    esac
done
```

Comment: Since those keys are side-by-side on most keyboards, I would guess a typo, and that it was intended to be `--` like the others.

Comment: I agree with @DarkFalcon. `==` isn't mentioned at all in the manual.

Comment: That was my first guess that `==` was mistaken with `--`, but since someone used nested functions definitions I wasn't so sure.